# Flutter how can i show value of list in a list

Tags: flutter

I have a data something like this i want to show the ID in a Text Widget

```
   {
        "Orders": [
            {
                "OrderID": 208,
                "Remarks": null,
                "OrderCheckouts": {
                    "OrderCheckoutID": 207,
                    "ID": 208,
                },
            }]
    }
```

I am printing `OrderID` now like this `posts.data[position]['OrderID']` Now i want to print the `ID` in `OrderCheckouts` and i am stuck on this :D I am trying but not able to get how can i do this.

I try like this also posts.data[position]['CustomerOrders']['Name'] but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code worked for me:

**Dart Code**

```dart
final json = {
  "Orders": [
    {
      "OrderID": 208,
      "Remarks": null,
      "OrderCheckouts": {
        "OrderCheckoutID": 207,
        "ID": 208,
      },
    }
  ]
};

void main() {
  json['Orders'].forEach((e) {
    print((e['OrderCheckouts'] as Map<String, dynamic>)['OrderCheckoutID']);
    print((e['OrderCheckouts'] as Map<String, dynamic>)['ID']);
  });
}
```

**Flutter Code**

```dart
final json = {
  "Orders": [
    {
      "OrderID": 208,
      "Remarks": null,
      "OrderCheckouts": {
        "OrderCheckoutID": 207,
        "ID": 208,
      },
    }
  ]
};

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dataList = json['Orders'];

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ...dataList
                .map<Widget>((e) => ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                        (e['OrderCheckouts'] as Map<String, dynamic>)['ID']
                            .toString())))
                .toList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Try it on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/2f8fa3125334bf1e2c916edc3f843e43)

Comment: I just need to show in a Text Widget. Something like Text(Orders[OrderCheckouts][Ids]))

Comment: I've updated my answer with a Flutter example using `Text` widget.

Comment: Is it not possible with out map ? Because i am showing some data like this posts.data['OrderID'] and now i am trying like this posts.data[position]['OrderCheckouts'] as Map<String, dynamic>)['ID'].toString() its showing error

Comment: Yes the map cast is important, could you describe which error you got ? Also there seems to be a parenthesis missing in the line you've posted.

Comment: I've tried the following `(data[position]['OrderCheckouts'] as Map)['ID'].toString()` and it is working.

Comment: i have try same as you say like this Text((data[position]['OrderCheckouts'] as Map)['ID'].toString()) its showing data isn't defined but in same widget the other values are showing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223763/discussion-between-guillaume-roux-and-umaiz-khan).